# iphone : Creating UIView with different background colors within for-loop

Tags: iphone, uiview

This might be a simple one. I am trying to create multiple UIView with different colors using a For-loop:

```
float colorGrade = 255.0 / 160;

for (int i = 0; i < 160; i++)
{
    float finalColor = colorGrade * i;
    if (finalColor > 255)
        finalColor = 255;

    UIView *viewColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 2, 0, 2, viewHeight)];
    UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:finalColor green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    [viewColor setAlpha:1];
    [viewColor setBackgroundColor:bgColor];
    [viewColor setTag:i + 1];

    [touchPadView addSubview:viewColor];
}
```

Views are created, but they are all ended up with the same colors. Something is missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:finalColor/255.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: oh gosh, forgotten about the division. damn! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one.Because your UIColor method requires a float from 0-1, not 0-255. You need to divide all your RGB values by 255.0.

```
float colorGrade = 255.0 / 160;

for (int i = 0; i < 160; i++)
{
    float finalColor = colorGrade * i;
    if (finalColor > 255)
        finalColor = 255;

    UIView *viewColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 2, 0, 2, viewHeight)];
    UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:finalColor/255.0f green:0.0f blue:0 alpha:1];
    [viewColor setAlpha:1];
    [viewColor setBackgroundColor:bgColor];
    [viewColor setTag:i + 1];

    [touchPadView addSubview:viewColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:finalColor/255.0f green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
```

Change the line to above.